# How long does a UIButton's label text take to change?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've taken over some iOS code where the logic checks the text of a UIButton's titleLabel before deciding what to do (yeah...not robust at all), and if it matches then the text is changed. This was causing an issue where the user could double press the button if they did so really quickly, and replacing it with a bool check solved it. My question is why? When you set the text, does it not do it instantly, or does it take an event cycle or two before it does?

```
if([self.button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Unused"])
{
    [self.button setTitle:@"Used" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that changes the button's title? I think this might have something to do with "system" style buttons in iOS7 animating title changes.

Comment: it takes an event cycle i guess. when ever you set `setNeedsToDisplay` that takes effect in next cycle

Comment: Are you setting the title via `setTitle forState`? or `button.titleLabel.text`?

Comment: I've just edited the code into the question.

Comment: What is this if statement wrapped in? Button pressed?

Comment: Yeah, it's in the callback method.

Comment: @Rajveer Try using a "custom" button instead of a "system" button.